# UITextField losing clearsOnBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a UITextField and set its clearsOnBeginEditing to true. But after calling becomeFirstResponder() manually it looses said property.
I was able to work around that problem by setting `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.
My question is why it is losing that property. And whether my workaround is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Add `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true;` after you call `textField.becomeFirstResponder();`

It is better to use `textField.xt=@"" in textFieldShouldBeginEditing` than using `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true in textFieldShouldBeginEditing`

Comment: Adding `textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = true` after calling `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` doesn't change anything. And why is manually clearing the text better?

Comment: You are trying to set the property clearsOnBeginEditing each time you begin the editing (textFieldShouldBeginEditing). This is not a good way.

Comment: Is there no way the textfield can keep the property? Otherwise i don't see the reason of having such a property.

Comment: The proper way is create the textfield--> set the property clearsOnBeginEditing in storyboard. Create and conect the IBOutlet. call the becomeFirstResponder() method

Comment: that is actually what i did

Answer (score 0):

If you `resignfirstresponder` that means `inputview` of textfield become `nil`. when you call `becomefirstresonder` then it's create new instance and assign to that textfield. so every settings are regenerated. hope this will help :)